# Why would MySQL 5.6.26-74.0 lock a select on a database1 while dropping a table on database2?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have a large table on database2, e.g., that I need to drop.  When I do, it takes 15 seconds or so, and during this time, selects on database1 (same server) block.  This happens every time on a mysql server that I run on a percona server I run on ubuntu 14.04, but I cannot reproduce it at all on my local box, running OS X, with the same percona server version.  I'm using Innodb on both.

Additional information: If I run delete from table1;  It works without hanging, but then still hangs when I drop the table with no rows in it.  I'm thinking it is doing some kind of file system cleanup that is blocking the whole server, but I can't find any documentation about / how to work around it.  my OS X box is using an HFS+ filesystem, and the Ubuntu box is using ext4.

Thanks :)

Comment: Check for `USE` statements setting the focus on the wrong db.  Are the filesystems the same (NTFS, EXT3, XFS, etc) in the two cases?

Comment: the file systems are different -- HFS+ in the OSX case, ext4 in the ubuntu case.  There are no USE statements happening.  I am able to reproduce in a fairly isolated / easy fashion on the Ubuntu box (although it is my production server that is having the issues, so I'm trying to avoid that too much).

Comment: If the database is "huge", then the OS is _possible_ responsible for taking a long time to delete the files and directory involved.  (Hence, my question about filesystems.)  I don't know those filesystems well enough to be sure this is the answer.